# Regular expression to find string inside curly brackets Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I am trying to get a substring which is inside curly brackets by using regular expression.

Assuming that I have the following string:

```
"This is a {nice} text to search for a {cool} substring".
```

I'd like to be able to search for `nice` and `cool`

Comment: `\{([^}]*)\}`, asked many times. or `string.match(/[^{}]*(?=\})/g)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj lol too tired to post answer ?? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try as follows:

```js
var myString = "This is a {nice} text to search for a {cool} substring",
  pattern = /[^{}]*(?=\})/g;

console.log(myString.match(pattern));
```