# Regular expression to find string inside curly brackets while keeping curly brackets

Tags: regex

Hi I am only starting out with Regexs, and am trying to write a regular expression to find string inside curly brackets while keeping curly brackets

```
Text: "This is a {nice} text to search for a {cool} substring".
Answer I want: {nice} and {cool}
```

I have already looked through the answer here:
[Regular expression to find string inside curly brackets Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483613/regular-expression-to-find-string-inside-curly-brackets-javascript)

This almost does what I want, except that it only returns what's inside the curly brackets. I want to keep the curl brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = "This is a {nice} text to search for a {cool} substring",
    pattern = /\{[^{}]*\}/g;

console.log(myString.match(pattern));
```

That's a modification of the answer to the question you linked. I added the `{` to the beginning of the pattern, and I removed the lookahead around the `}` at the end.